# A line bundle on the wedge sum of spheres associated to a polynomial $P(z)\in \mathbb{C}[z]$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Assume  that $P\in \mathbb{C}[z]$ is a  polynomial of degree $n$ with $n$  distinct roots $z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n$.

We identify $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{R}$. Put $a_i=(z_i,0)$.

Then $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ is  the  union of $\mathbb{R}^{3\geq0} \setminus \{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\} $ and $\mathbb{R}^{3\leq0} \setminus \{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\} $ where $\mathbb{R}^{3\geq0}=\mathbb{C} \times [0, +\infty)$ and $\mathbb{R}^{3\leq0}=\mathbb{C} \times (-\infty, 0]$.

This  enable us  to define  a  complex line  bundle on  $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ using  clutching function $1/P(z)$.

Since the wedge   sum of  $n$, $S^2$  is  a  deformation retract  of  $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$, we  get  a  line bundle on the wedge   sum of  the spheres.

> Does  the  isometric  class of this  line  bundle depend on choosing initial polynomial $P(z)$?  What is  the explicit formulation of  the (first) Chern  class of this  line  bundle,  in $\oplus_{i=1}^n \mathbb{Z}$, the  cohomology of the base  space?( In terms of  the  coefficients of  $P(z)$)

Comment: This should be an exercise in complex analysis. The coefficient of the Chern class on the sphere corresponding to $a_k$ should be computed as follows: take a small circle which winds once around $a_k$, take its image under the transformation $1/P(z)$, and compute the winding number of this curve around $a_k$. My guess is its the residue of the pole, or something lie that.

Comment: @MarkGrant  Thank you. For  $P(z)=z$ we  get the  tautological line  bundle  over $\mathbb{C}P^1\simeq S^2$. But  may you elaborate your comment for  arbitrary $P$.

Comment: if I remembered enough complex analysis to do this easily, I wouldn't have set it as an exercise ;) I believe it should follow from the residue theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem and my comment above. If nobody more knowledgeable comes along, I might have a go later.

Comment: @MarkGrant  thanks  for this new comment.  I do  not  think the residue effect on  Chern classes . For  example  for P(z)=az , a in C, the line bundle is the Tautological bundle  because az is homotopic to bz  for  $a\neq b$ . right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's how I think it goes. No need for the residue theorem or anything like that.

Let $S_k$ denote the sphere corresponding to $z_k$. To compute the Chern class of the restriction of your line bundle to $S_k$, it suffices to compute the degree of the map 
$$
f:S^1\to S^1,\qquad f(z) = \frac{|P(z)|}{P(z)} = \frac{\overline{P(z)}}{|P(z)|}
$$
obtained by restricting your clutching function $1/P(z)$ to a small circle $S^1\subset\mathbb{C}$ which encloses $z_k$ and contains no other roots in its interior, and normalizing. But since this $f$ is the composition of the map $z\mapsto P(z)/|P(z)|$ of degree $n$ and the map $z\mapsto \bar{z}$ of degree $-1$, and since the degree of a composition is the product of the degrees, the degree of $f$ is $-n$.

Therefore I think that the Chern class of your bundle over $\vee_n S^2$ is $-n$ times the generator of each sphere.

Comment: Thank you for your  answer. Is $ \overline{P(z)} = P(\overline{z})$ essential in your  argument? The  coefficients are not  necessarily real

Comment: @AliTaghavi: Oops, my mistake. No, I don't think so. I've corrected this and another mistake (I'd used $w^{-1}=\bar{w}/|w|$ instead of $w^{-1}=\bar{w}/|w|^2$ before).